# Get element by id in vue and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to get a dom element by id using vuejs. The problem is I don't know how to access this element. I'm using this.$refs. When I write console.log(this.$refs) I see the following:

[image]

But when I write console.log(this.$refs.gauge2) I see undefined.
Does anyone know how to access this element?
This is my code:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
var Gauge = require('svg-gauge')

export default Vue.extend({
    components: {
    },
    created(){
        console.log(this.$refs)
        console.log(this.$refs.$gauge2)
        var element = this.$refs.gauge2
        var gauge2 = Gauge(
            element, {
                min: -50,
                max: 50,
                dialStartAngle: 180,
                dialEndAngle: 0,
                value: 50
            }
        );
    },
})
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="gauge2" ref="gauge2" class="gauge-container two">
            <span class="label">.two</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Thank you

Comment: can you include the code where you call `console.log(this.$refs.gauge2)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to access a ref from the created method which is called before the template has rendered.
You can access refs only after the template has been rendered, I would suggest using the mounted function.

For more information:

- [Vue.js Lifecycle Diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)

**EDIT**
Take a look at this picture, taken from the official Vue.js Website:

[Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

[image: Refs from Vue.js official website]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
this.$refs.gauge2.$el.id
```

and by changing the trigger to the mounted() hook:

Comment: If I write this I get the following typescript error: TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Vue'.

Comment: I get the same error: TS2339: Property '$el' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
  Property '$el' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Comment: Maybe is a problem with the loader?

Comment: Try to change to mounted() instead of created() and also please paste here the result of console.log(this.$refs.gauge2). Then if I may, why you need the id?

Answer (score 0):

[image: This would be helpful for you to solve your issue]

```
this.$refs.gauge2.id
```

if you get `undefined` value, the reason is that the `console.log` command was run before assigning `ref` (gauge2) to this element.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it changing the method created by mounted. Now it works thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read the Vue lifecycle page in the documentation to avoid other mistakes like that : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks